# Is a passport or a national ID card valid on its expiration date?

Tags: passports, eu-id-card

I am wondering if a document like a passport or a national ID card is valid *on* its expiration date.

For example, if my passport says "Valid until 2019/05/04", could I still use it to cross the border today?
I found this ambiguous: does the validity include the date that's listed under this field?

I am looking for a general answer or one applicable in EU.

Comment: No matter whether a legal interpretation can be dug up somewhere, I wouldn't chance it. You have no immediate way to _force_ a person in authority to follow your legal reference over his idea of common sense, and even if you manage to get vindicated later, the hours and days of your life that would eat up will surely much outweigh the minor hassle of _just renewing the passport already_.

Comment: There is also a difference between EU countries and whether you go out or go home.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks for your comment, maybe that's the answer already? 
Willeke I would use it to go abroad and then back home the same day.

Comment: What if you are delayed either way and end up having to travel on the next day? Also remember than some countries state that your passport must be valid for some time after entry (usually 3 or 6 months, often related to the duration of visa-free travel).

Comment: I expect that this is true of most countries. Though I occasionally see a note in Timatic saying that some country's document is actually considered to have expired at the end of the day before its printed expiration date.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have seen such a note that said, if I recall correctly, that the destination country considers that *other* countries' documents expire at the end of the day before the printed expiration date.  Those who want to insist that the document is actually valid until the end of the printed date might prefer to think of this as an extra validity requirement of one day instead of the usual three or six moths. :-)

Comment: And to add confusion, they are now millions of French ID cards that are valid 5 years beyond the date printed on them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is applicable to the EU:

> Passports for British citizens are valid for travel to any EU country up to and including the passport expiry date.

([Source](https://www.tui.co.uk/destinations/info/passport-information))

You can travel on the expiry date depending on the country, some require a certain amount of validity on the passport. In the EU there is no such requirement:

> All 28 countries in the European Union require that your passport is valid for the duration of your stay.

([Source](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/identity/soon-to-expire-passport))

The same applies with ID cards:

> We can only accept a EU Identity Card that is valid and within its expiry date. This would be the same for any identification documents. All would need to be within their expiry dates.

([Source](https://www.supportcentre-rbs.co.uk/Searchable/913251482/My-EU-Identity-Card-has-expired-can-I-still-use-it-to-confirm-my-identification-ID-online.htm))

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Were you able to find this information in an official source somewhere? While I would indeed expect a travel agency to know something like this, I would appreciate a .gov source or something of the sort. (A bank can also have their own criteria, different from the ones for travel.)

Comment: @Fato39 see under the validity section https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain/entry-requirements this applies to the rest of the EU as well, not just Spain

Comment: Since EU citizens have a right to stay indefinitely in other EU countries, subject only to very limited conditions, they are not generally going to be denied entry on the basis of an expiring document, especially if their stay is long enough for them to apply for and receive a replacement document while they are there.